# How can I use an interface extension as a parameter and test for an extra property?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, extends, typechecking

Consider the following code (playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQAkCHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNwEC+BoksiKAwgBbAANgBNkEAB6QQIjGkw58xAA70ycKAE9eOMIjCoNEcNVr0QzNgQQ5aNcsqEQAYgFcQCMMBwB1KHGVlaGQAXmQYd09vEAAKBEFRagFhEQBKJSIoCDBXKFwMByc3Dy8cOIS0pmQAemqAdywoAGs5GFAIKxsQOwKyRxdI0twwiJLogB5UcSljWXkobBAAPhighZxqVHTCImAYGLBNIKwYZDXFgDpVYHUtHXB9QyzwZABCELCAcncRCDaQCAiT7bYhELrYJwXIRYBgxT6oNQaTTILp6TxnIwvYByT7IADUZwUICuiLuukemLAqRYRHYu32n2ut205M8T2MYFxoEJ6xAIKIYNsWEh0Nh8NJyNR+gxzzAyGxyFxBPOOBJNyR9zRBkp1OI7HYQA)).

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}
interface Child extends Person {
    primaryContactParent: string;
}
const sampleFunctionWrapper = function(child: Child) {
    return sampleFunction(child); //works fine
}
const sampleFunction = function<P extends Person>(person: P) {
    if(typeof person.primaryContactParent !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Primary contact parent is ' + person.primaryContactParent);
    }
    if('primaryContactParent' in person) {
        console.log('Primary contact parent is ' + person.primaryContactParent);
    }
}
```

The repeated error is TS(2339):
`Property 'primaryContactParent' does not exist on type 'P'.`

The parameter type P **extends** Person but the type checker won't permit even checking for the presence of any field not defined on Person itself.  I could certainly understand not guaranteeing the presence of anything not defined on Person, but to not even be able to check for the field of something which might extend it has me a bit puzzled.
In what way am I misunderstanding the possibilities of using one interface that `extends` another?

Answer (score 1):

To get this working you need to specify `P` to extend `Person` or `Child`.

```
const sampleFunction = function<P extends Person | Child>(person: P) {
    if('primaryContactParent' in person) {
        console.log('Primary contact parent is ' + person.primaryContactParent);
    }
}
```

With a constraint like `extends Person` we signal the function that it can expect a type with a capabilities of `Person` and the type system will not allow to access anything outside of these capabilities.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to avoid specifying every possible descendant type because there are quite a few and the list becomes a maintainability sore spot. I also think I found other cases where it doesn't actually restrict to just what's defined in Person when the type was defined as one that extends Person, so it seemed possible.

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use to get type safety here is to create a helper function to check for the existence of the property. This way you can type the helper function so that it will inform TypeScript of that prop's existence via a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Eg, something like:

```
function hasProp<P extends string>(obj: {}, prop: P): obj is Record<P, unknown> {
    return prop in obj;
}
```

Then, if you use that function to check instead, the property will exist and will have the type `unknown` inside of the `if` block's scope:

```
const sampleFunction = function<P extends Person>(person: P) {
    if (hasProp(person, "primaryContactParent")) {
        console.log("Primary contact parent is " + person.primaryContactParent); // No error.
    }
}
```

---

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAVYGcD2ZUDewAkGAgLZQBcqWEM4A5gNzAC%20woksiKqAwgAsQAGwAmqKAA9oYMVgzY8hEgAcG5BDACe-PBGQR0WqJBp0GYFu05I8dWhVUioAMQCuYJBBB4A6jAIqqqwqAC8qHCe3r5gABRIwuI0QqJiAJQqxDBQEO4w%20FhOLh5ePngJSRnMqAD0tQDuODAA1gpw4FA2wFFlsaiCCFjoMDiqADzokjKm8rT0TAB8cTgARgBWNARsADSo6mM06Ok0a%20uoIAoASlB2MGKTe54tYDgNYItZOXkF%206OqF3wZ1YHGAdjADiK5Gcbmi5XwEV6MTwk2msjmmBguA%20cRCWLwR0yRGIIDgcQg2hCODg%20yUYAAdOoQJodHpIIZjDlIKgAIRhCIAck8YigHTAUDEAqJJGI4NwLnpIhwjDiApGzK02lQ4IM3n2Jm5l1QAtQAGpafiGUyWbp9ByDRB0qxiBwSWSBdbNWzdUYHSbwBbsdLiLL7DgFUqVWqNJrtXa9aoHRcFCbzXjsYyY6z476uY7na7Sag4oNhv9cXS9gAiT3Z9neTmmCBV9LB0MQ8NQRXKuJV9U2uP1iD6vPJ1BVs2BvCZjV1n2NyBOkgcDhAA)